# Image Reveal Animation On Swiper Slider Using Gsap

Tags: html, css, animation, swiper.js, gsap

I am trying Image Reveal animation on swiper slider I achieve to get the animation its working fine in the first slide I am stuck in when the change to other slides the animations are not working I have used  [event for changing other slides](https://swiperjs.com/api/#initialize) I am trying to get when clicking on next arrow the animation start. when there is slide change. I am stuck in these please someone point me in the right direction.  Thanks in advance.

**Achieve Code**: [codepen](https://codepen.io/asiyafatima_12/pen/KKPGaME)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     var mainslider = new Swiper('.slider-main', {
       pagination: {
         el: '.swiper-pagination',
         type: 'progressbar',
       },
       navigation: {
         nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
         prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
       },
     });
  
  // click next arrow for another slide animation
  mainslider.on('slideChange', function () {
   var controller2 = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
   $(".ansa-landing-wrap").each(function() {
    var tl = new TimelineMax();
    var cov = $(this).find(".cover");
    var img = $(this).find(".ansa-slider");
     tl.from(cov, 1, { scaleX: 0, transformOrigin: "left" });
     tl.to(cov, 1, { scaleX: 0, transformOrigin: "right" }, "reveal");
     tl.from(img, 1, { opacity: 0 }, "reveal");
    var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
     triggerElement: this,
     triggerHook: 0.7,
    })
    .setTween(tl)
    .addIndicators()
    .addTo(controller2);
   });
   alert('testing');
  });
      
  //Slider Animationon first slide
   var controller1 = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
 $(".slider-main").each(function() {
    var tl = new TimelineMax();
    var cov = $(this).find(".cover");
    var img = $(this).find(".img-slider");
    tl.from(cov, 1, { scaleX: 0, transformOrigin: "left" });
    tl.to(cov, 1, { scaleX: 0, transformOrigin: "right" }, "reveal");
    tl.from(img, 1, { opacity: 0 }, "reveal");
    var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
      triggerElement: this,
      triggerHook: 0.7
    })
     .setTween(tl)
     .addIndicators()
     .addTo(controller1);
 });
  
  });
```

```css
.swiper-slide {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
.swiper-pagination-progressbar {
 bottom: 0;
}

.swiper-container-horizontal>.swiper-pagination-progressbar {
    top: auto;
   bottom: 48px;
}
.swiper-container-horizontal>.swiper-pagination-progressbar {
    width: 20%;
    height: 4px;
 left: 48%;
 top: 95%;
    background-color: rgba(232, 227, 227, 0.2);
}
.swiper-pagination-progressbar .swiper-pagination-progressbar-fill {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f06a44;
 }
h2 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: left;
}
.swiper-slide:nth-Child(even){
    background: #cccccc;
}

.swiper-slide:nth-Child(odd){
    background: #666666;
}

.caption {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.counter, .counter span {
    position:relative;
}
.counter .next, .counter .count {
    position:absolute;
}
.counter .next {
    transform:translateY(-12px);
    left:0;
}
.sl {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh - 100px);
    z-index: 1;
}
 img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.cover {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="swiper-container slider-main">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide sl">
            <img class="img-slider"  src="https://i.ibb.co/92rG5SH/ts4.jpg">
          <div class="cover"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide sl">
            <img class="img-slider" src="https://i.ibb.co/9TXDX3G/ol2.jpg">
          <div class="cover"></div>
      </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide sl">
        <img class="img-slider" src="https://i.ibb.co/Wxx3h1N/pim-chu-294493-unsplash.jpg">
          <div class="cover"></div>
        </div> 
    </div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination fraction"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
</div>
<span class="fraction"></span>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/css/swiper.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.6/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.6/plugins/animation.gsap.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.6/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It seems to be working for me. What is going wrong?

Comment: @Zach Saucier: actually, I want image reveal animation which is working fine on the first slide but when sliding next slide animation its not coming.

Comment: Ah, I see. In general you should be creating all of your tweens inside of your timelines *before* you play them and have that timeline be paused. Then, when the time comes, you play them. It might make sense to attach the timeline to the element, using something like `this.timeline = new TimelineMax();`

Comment: Out of topic - Please use `console.log` (Instead of alert).
Hard to see the example like this.

Comment: @Zach Saucier: According to your suggestion I have tried by using this.timeline = new TimelineMax(); but there is no changes. can you please help me. I am really stuck in this animation.

Comment: Just adding a reference like that won't fix your issue. You've got to do the first part of my comment: setting up the timelines before you need to play them.